# Approximate upper bound on eigenvalues of $I-A$ where $A$ is a sparse matrix wherein each row sums to 1.0

Tags: linear-algebra, convergence-divergence, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, sparse-matrices

Suppose $A$ is a large matrix with the following properties:

1. $A$ is $n\times n$
2. $A$ is sparse (with each row having at most 8 non-zero coefficients, regardless of $n$)
3. $A$'s diagonal has only zeros.
4. Each row of $A$ sums to 1.0 (i.e. $A$ transforms each element to the weighted average of 8 "neighbors" in some sense)
5. FWIW: Non-zero coefficients in $A$ are "typically" not very far from $\frac{1}{8}$ but could in principle be anywhere in $\mathbb{R}$.

What is a good way (criterion/algorithm) to find an upper bound on the magnitude of the eigenvalues of $I-A$?

In particular I seek to find $s\in\mathbb{R}$ that guarantees that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{A-I}{s})^n=0$ (even if $s$ is, say, up to 200% of the largest eigenvalue).

Could property 4 perhaps allow us to set $s$ to the greatest magnitude of any coefficient in $A$?

Comment: A matrix with all row sum equal $l$ has $l$ as eigenvalue and all $1$ vector a corresponding eigenvector.

Comment: @ToniMhax Thank you for pointing that out. I've edited the question.

Comment: Just a comment the introduction of $x$ is unnecessary the question would be about the convergence of $\{A,A^2,\ldots\}$ the eigenvalues of $A-I$ are those of $A$ -1 so this is also irrelevant, lastly for the $s$ fraction $1/s$ can't be >1 as the largest eigenvalue of $\frac{A}{s}$ exceeds 1 and diverges the sequence

Comment: @ToniMhax Thanks; do any of those observations apply to the latest edit of the question? I don't follow why $A-I$ is irrelevant as it does alter the relative magnitudes/ranking of eigenvalues (compared to those of $A$).

Comment: Ok in that edit the eigenvalues of $B=A-I$ are bounded by the maximum row sum in absolute values i.e. $|\lambda(A-I)|\le \max_i(\sum_j|b_{ij}|)=b$ so that $s=b$ suffices to get $\lambda(\frac{A-I}{s})<1$